# Chrome giving a Bus error (core dumped) error after manual fsck

Tags: google-chrome, fsck

I am unable to open Chrome. Opening it via the launcher in the GUI causes the icon to flash a few times, then I get no response. If I try in the terminal it just comes back with a single

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

message and that's it.

I have tried running `apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable` and it finished successfully, but did not affect the problem.

A little background: This morning, I was trying to open a spreadsheet and my computer was not responding.  I decided it was time for a reboot anyway, so I did. When the machine came back up, it went to a system screen that indicated that there had been a problem and said

```
the root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck
```

I did the manual `fsck`, there were a number of files that I told it to fix.  I did notice there were a number that mentioned Chrome.

After the `fsck` was complete, I rebooted and my machine started as normal.  As far as I can tell, everything was then working fine except Chrome. When starting Chrome, it would pop up a message telling me that it had failed previously and gave me an option to relaunch.  If I tried to relaunch it, but it didn't do anything.  I decided to try one more fresh, clean, reboot.  Since then the GUI reports nothing and the terminal only the `Bus error`.

I have not attempted to reinstall with `apt-get` yet.

Any help at all would be great.  There seem to be a number of hits when searching for errors that seem similar with the core dump, but most have no answer at all, an outdated answer to remove files that no longer exist in the current structure, or answers that are irrelevant to my situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly heavy handed resolution, but it worked:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then I went to both `~/.config` and `~/.cache` and renamed the `google-chrome` folders to `xgoogle-chrome` in each just as backups (probably not necessary).

Reboot.

Reinstall from `.deb`

Comment: Thanks. Although in my case, I just had to remove the cache and the config folder. Didn't need to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 I faced the `Bus Error (core dumped)` after an update, so the following worked for me:

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome/Default ~/.config/google-chrome/DefaultBackup
```

PS: Probably it's safe to delete that folder as well, since another one will be generated automatically on next startup

(inspired from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VsbqWqMHOAI;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/ubuntu)).